# How to select menu item in Android System Recovery? LG Optimus One P500

Tags: lg-optimus-one, recovery-mode

I'm started my LG Optimus One in System Recovery Mode. Vol Up/Vol Down buttons works - moving up/down through the menu. But i can't start menu item, for example 'reboot system now', or 'apply sdcard:update.zip'.

Answer (score 2):

What type of System Recovery do you have? On my P500 everything is fine.

In AmonRA Recovery there are such bindings:

- VolUp/VolDown - moving through menus
- Back - previous menu level, cancel action
- Menu - select menu item, approve action

Also I've noted that from some time back button doesn't work every time as I press it. I think it is hardware problem. Maybe I need to disassemble phone and make it maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you click the Power button to select items.  That's how my Galaxy S works, anyways.

**Edit:** According to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8741280&postcount=1), try using the Send Call button.  And End Call for cancel.  Or according to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=15523529&postcount=3), use the Camera button.  I guess it depends on what recovery you have installed.  Try selecting something that won't do any harm -- a further menu, for example.  Not "factory reset" :P

Comment: LG P500 has Menu, Home, Back, Search, Vol Up, Vol Down, Power buttons. I'm tried all of them :(

Answer (score 0):

if you're use the same custom recovery, according to [this](http://www.lg-phones.org/lg-optimus-one-custom-recovery.html), on P500 to select item you press Menu button.